# Ruby on Rails prevent nil error when it is assumed record may not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, belongs-to, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-one

I am building a simple book check out application. One of the things that I need to do is determine if a book is checked out. I have my associations between my people and book classes setup through a book_check_out class. My goal is to use the checked_out property of book to determine if a book is presently checked out. However, in my present implementation when a book is not checked out and I reference book.checked_out.XXX I receieve the error "*You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!*" My goal is to use book.checked_out for two purposes in some views show that yes, that book is checked out and in other views show who it is presently checked out to.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_check_outs
  has_many :books, :through => :book_check_outs
end
```

---

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_check_outs
  has_many :people, :through => :book_check_outs

  def checked_out
    book_check_outs || false
  end
end
```

---

```
class BookCheckOut < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've got a boolean outcome, something that can either be true or false (for instance, a book can either be checked out or not), you need to assume a default for the outcome. In this case, we can assume it's false (the book is not checked out by default).

In the book model, remove your *has_many :checked_out* line and create a method with the same name:

```
def checked_out
  book_check_outs || false
end
```

This *should* return either the BookCheckOuts, or if there are none associated with the instance, FALSE. It gives you a quick, easy, foolproof method of checking an association and removing the nasty nil object error.

**Edit** You could also just return TRUE or FALSE, and not return the most recent checkouts by checking that book_check_outs is nil or not. Rails provides a method called blank? which calls both nil? and empty?

```
def checked_out
  !book_check_outs.blank?
end
```

I love Ruby :)

Comment: This unfortunately, returns an error "uninitialized constant Book::BookCheckOuts". I like the idea though my only concern is that I am not attempting to get at the BookCheckOuts collection if it's been checked_out just the most recent check out and if its not checked out returning false is perfect.

Comment: I did receive the "uninitialized constant Book::BookCheckOuts" until I changed both to book_check_outs. I think it has to do w/ the database naming convention.

Comment: Sorry about that, late night responding and all that, brain got foggy and forgot that you needed to access the generated accessor not the class.

Answer (score 0):

I forget if it actually matters or not, but for clarity's sake you might want to put the has_many relation above the has_many :through relation.

I am also not sure you should be declaring in the Book class that it has_many :BookCheckOuts AND it has_one :checked_out, since the checked_out *actually* is a BookCheckOut which you declared it having many of above.

Comment: I agree w/ the has_many and has_one it feels a bit awkward. I am looking for the "right" way of going about this. I've switched the has_many and has_many through. I too am not sure if it matters but I agree your suggestion makes things more clear.

Comment: Well, I guess the question I have is: do you have multiple copies of the same book in your library, and thus could loan out different ones?  If _not_ then you only really need a has_one relationship.  If you _do_ have multiple copies then you might want to have something like a PhysicalBook model which is a representation of each physical book you have...